# CGAL refine_fair_example.cpp

Tags: c++14, cgal

I am from JAVA background so new to CPP and cgal. i am not able to understand the meaning of syntax `e(v->vertex_begin()), e_end(e)`. What is `e` here?
Can someone please help me in understanding this syntax.

Polygon_mesh_processing/refine_fair_example.cpp
Polyhedron::Halfedge_around_vertex_circulator `e(v->vertex_begin()), e_end(e);`

Answer (score 0):

`e` and `e_end` are variable of type `Polyhedron::Halfedge_around_vertex_circulator`. It is a circulator type that will provide the halfedges around a vertex. `e_end` is initialized as a copy of `e`.

if you have a loop like:

```
do{
   Polyhedron::Halfedge_handle h = e;
   ....
}
while( ++e!=e_end);
```

You can get all halfedges around a vertex.